# How to create a UnityNancyBootstrapper-implementation that will work with a OWIN Startup class

Tags: unity-container, owin, nancy

I'm trying to create a Nancy/Unity-bootstrapper that can work with a OWIN-startup-class like the one described here:

[Minimal sample: Self hosted Nancy using Owin, Unity bootstrapper including xUnit test](http://www.stefanbader.ch/minimal-sample-self-hosted-nancy-using-owin-unity-bootstrapper-including-xunit-test/)

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

        container.RegisterType<IMessageHelper, MessageHelper>();

        app.UseNancy(new NancyOptions
        {
            EnableClientCertificates = true,
            Bootstrapper = new NancyOwinBoxBootstrapper(container)
        });
    }
}

public class NancyOwinBoxBootstrapper : UnityNancyBootstrapper
{
    private IUnityContainer _container;

    public NancyOwinBoxBootstrapper(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    protected override IUnityContainer GetApplicationContainer()
    {
        return _container;
    }
}
```

The sample contained in the NancyOwinBox.zip works fine, but it is based on Nancy.Bootstrappers.Unity version 1.1. When i upgrade the NuGet package to the latest version (1.2) the sample fails with:

Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "Nancy.Bootstrapper.IApplicationStartup", name = "Nancy.ViewEngines.ViewEngineApplicationStartup".
Exception occurred while: while resolving.

### Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The current type, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Nancy.ViewEngines.IViewEngine], is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

At the time of the exception, the container was:

Resolving Nancy.ViewEngines.ViewEngineApplicationStartup,Nancy.ViewEngines.ViewEngineApplicationStartup (mapped from Nancy.Bootstrapper.IApplicationStartup, Nancy.ViewEngines.ViewEngineApplicationStartup)
  Resolving parameter "viewEngines" of constructor Nancy.ViewEngines.ViewEngineApplicationStartup(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[Nancy.ViewEngines.IViewEngine, Nancy, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] viewEngines, Nancy.ViewEngines.IViewCache viewCache, Nancy.ViewEngines.IViewLocator viewLocator)
    Resolving System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Nancy.ViewEngines.IViewEngine],(none)

The current type, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Nancy.ViewEngines.IViewEngine], is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

Does anyone have an idea why this error occurs?

Comment: At some point the container is trying to resolve ViewEngineApplicationStartup.  ViewEngineApplicationStartup has one constructor: `ViewEngineApplicationStartup(IEnumerable<IViewEngine> viewEngines, IViewCache viewCache, IViewLocator viewLocator)` so Unity uses that constructor and then needs to inject the appropriate dependencies.  The first dependency is IEnumerable<IViewEngine> viewEngines and Unity does not know how to resolve IEnumerable<IViewEngine> and throws.  Usually you would register a mapping between an interface and an implementation (and in this case also an IEnumerable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register the `EnumerableExtension` in your container, like so:

```
container.AddNewExtension<EnumerableExtension>();
```

See [UnityNancyBootstrapper.cs](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy.Bootstrappers.Unity/blob/master/src/Nancy.Bootstrappers.Unity/UnityNancyBootstrapper.cs#L86) for Reference.

Comment: Yep. I made a [pull request](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy.Bootstrappers.Unity/pull/10) to have this added to the readme months ago but hasn't been merged yet.